# XML inflation and EditText

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I've posted another question on this, but im asking another as the problem has been narrowed down some what. My problem is that I'm getting null pointer exception from inside the inner onClick at the line where the first String strTime is created. It has been suggested the reason for this is the poptest.xml not inflating properly. Can anyone see why this is happening?

I have this method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.newappt:

       final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.poptest);
       dialog.setTitle("Create New Appointment");
       dialog.setCancelable(true);

       Button buttoncancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
       buttoncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // on click for cancel button
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });

       Button buttonsave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button02);
       buttonsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // on click for save button   
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             String strTime = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.evnttime)).getText().toString();

             String strTitle = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.evnttitle)).getText().toString();

             String strDet = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.evntdet)).getText().toString();



            cursor = getAppts();
            addAppt(strTime, strTitle, strDet);
            showAppts(cursor);
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
       });

       dialog.show();
        break;

    case R.id.delappt:
        rmvall();
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if your `EditText` are in the `Dialog`:

```
String strTime = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.evnttime)).getText().toString();
String strTitle = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.evnttitle)).getText().toString();
String strDet = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.evntdet)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         String strTime = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.evnttime)).getText().toString();

         String strTitle = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.evnttitle)).getText().toString();

         String strDet = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.evntdet)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

my first guess would be that the findViewById inside the onClick listener is searching for R.id.evnttime as a child of buttonsave.

the findViewById method belongs to the View class and is therefore availlale to every sub class like Buttons, Layouts... 
It is searching up to the last children of the view you use it on.

Possible solutions here: 
find your views outside of the onClick method or use the findViewById function of the main view (dialog).

Comment: `findViewById()` (without specifying a View) is part of your `Activity` so it will always look into the view hierarchy you set with e.g. `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. (Dialogs are not part of that hierarchy)

Comment: you are right, but also this findViewById() is originated in the  android.view package. Because with setContentView() you set the window resource. The findViewById() of an Activity is then defined by "return getWindow().findViewById(id);" :)